"mdadm --grow" is stuck. How can I safely cancel the operation?
I had raid5 8TB * 4
then ,now I added one more 8TB drive and try to make raid5 grow
$mdadm --grow /dev/md128 --raid-disks=5

It comes to 6.1% but it stuck for a few days, and number 482870548 doesn't move any more.
less /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md128 : active raid5 sdk[6] sdh3[0] sdi[4] sdj[5] sdg3[1]
      23427528384 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/5] [UUUUU]
      [=>...................]  reshape =  6.1% (482870548/7809176128) finish=63150741.3min speed=1K/sec

However it still consumes 100% CPU
$top

10070 root      20   0       0      0      0 R 100.0  0.0   3639:00 md128_raid5                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   8:27.71 rcu_sched                                                                                                               
 1400 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0  21:12.08 kswapd0                                                                                                                 
 2507 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0  12:18.42 usb-storage                                                                                                             
 2561 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   2:30.18 kworker/1:1H                                                                                                            
28016 root      20   0   28904   3428   2780 R   0.3  0.1   0:00.02 top                                                                                                                     
    1 root      20   0  138992   5400   3372 S   0.0  0.1   0:08.39 systemd                                                                                                                 
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.04 kthreadd                                                                                                                
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  14:01.07 ksoftirqd/0     

I checked the situation with this
$mdadm -D /dev/md128

/dev/md128:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Sep 22 08:59:59 2020
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 23427528384 (22342.23 GiB 23989.79 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 7809176128 (7447.41 GiB 7996.60 GB)
      Raid Devices : 5
     Total Devices : 5
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Wed Jul 24 09:24:26 2024
             State : clean, reshaping 
    Active Devices : 5
   Working Devices : 5
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : unknown

    Reshape Status : 6% complete
     Delta Devices : 1, (4->5)

              Name : 0a438048:RaidSecond-0  (local to host 0a438048)
              UUID : a9bcec2a:5772e6a5:045f28ac:62ae0002
            Events : 53642

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8      115        0      active sync   /dev/sdh3
       1       8       99        1      active sync   /dev/sdg3
       5       8      144        2      active sync   /dev/sdj
       4       8      128        3      active sync   /dev/sdi
       6       8      160        4      active sync   /dev/sdk

Also , I can't find the reason why it stuck and I am not what is the safe way to escape this situation.
So, How can I stop the safely with this process?
Or is there any other place to check ?

For now my raid is stuck like this ,
So, I made my mind to give up growing.
 mdadm -D /dev/md128
/dev/md128:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Sep 22 08:59:59 2020
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 23427528384 (22342.23 GiB 23989.79 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 7809176128 (7447.41 GiB 7996.60 GB)
      Raid Devices : 5
     Total Devices : 5
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sat Jul 27 01:18:05 2024
             State : clean, reshaping 
    Active Devices : 5
   Working Devices : 5
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : unknown

    Reshape Status : 6% complete
     Delta Devices : 1, (4->5)

              Name : 0a438048:RaidSecond-0  (local to host 0a438048)
              UUID : a9bcec2a:5772e6a5:045f28ac:62ae0002
            Events : 53644

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8      115        0      active sync   /dev/sdh3
       1       8       99        1      active sync   /dev/sdg3
       5       8      144        2      active sync   /dev/sdj
       4       8      128        3      active sync   /dev/sdi
       6       8      160        4      active sync   /dev/sdk

then I would like to do this, and remove /dev/sdk
 $mdadm /dev/md128 --grow --raid-devices=4

However with this command, how mdadm understood the target drive is /dev/sdk?
Or is there any good method to shrink the Raid5?

Check dmesg, smartctl -a, etc. just to make sure there is no hardware misbehavior involved. If everything looks fine but md still got stuck, that's usually a bug in the kernel.
To undo grow, there is mdadm --assemble --update=revert-reshape, but it involves stopping/restarting the array and it usually can't be done on a running kernel where md is already stuck due to a kernel bug; so you might have to reboot (there's a chance the reboot could get stuck as well; with kernel bugs, you never know).
At this point, you might as well let the grow proceed, and hope it doesn't get stuck again. You can try your luck with a different kernel version…
As a whole the revert-reshape is used rarely, it's not even documented properly, so it should be considered an experimental feature.

I try this mdadm --assemble --update=revert-reshape /dev/md128 however mdadm: /dev/md128 not identified in config file.

Maybe I should give up my new HDD (/dev/sdk) and reinstall another one. However in my understanding, I should reduce one(/dev/sdk) at first ,then add new one, but I cant reduce one for now.

--assemble only works if you --stop first. There's no point blindly replacing HDDs, if you can't point out a hardware problem. Growing/Reshaping involves locking and other things in the kernel, and unfortunately kernel md driver has a history of being buggy in this aspect, so it can get stuck on 100% CPU or otherwise end in a deadlock. You can check the linux-raid mailing list, stuck md grow is a reoccuring theme. It might resume normally if you simply reboot, or it might not. Reverting is just as risky (if not more so) than letting it finish.

It has the same problem after rebooting stuck like this (dmesg log)  [ 3007.643111] INFO: task mount:9548 blocked for more than 1000 seconds. [ 3007.643113]       Tainted: P           O    4.4.218.x86_64.1 #1 [ 3007.643115] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.

I am not sure it is hte physical problem or not, however deadlock still contunes after rebooting.

Try it with a different kernel. I'm not sure which bugs there may be in 4.4.218 ... at least one such bug was fixed in 6.5 so you could find a way to boot current 6.6 LTS kernel. For example using System Rescue. Not sure what else to suggest, sorry.

Thank you very much, I will try to use another machine , fortunately my drives are in the USB HDD box, so it can be moved.
